# Dynamic INDIRECT formula with range

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have some dynamic input, in my case, the name of the month in cell I25. Based on the month the function in cell H32 should reference a sheet with the name of the month and cell A18 within that sheet. Now this I can handle and have made it possible through the INDIRECT function.

The issue I'm having is with dynamic range. For example, I would like cell H33 to reference cell A19 within the worksheet "February". The closest I got to it was `=INDIRECT($I$25"&"!A18:A200")`. And it seems to be working, but for some strange reason it starts referencing the cells contents from A36 onwards, which I don't get. Suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one in `H32` and drag it down:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $I$25 & "'!" & CELL("address",A18))
```

**Notes:**

1. I've changed `$I$25 & "!"` to `"'" & $I$25 & "'!"` in formula to make it more reliable (for the case when sheet name contains spaces you should include your sheet name in single quotes like this: `'My sheet'!A18`)
2. In `H32` this formula evaluates to `=Feb!A18` (where `Feb` is your sheet name), in `H33` to `=Feb!A19` and so on.

Comment: Oh that worked beautifully, thank you so much, had been stuck on it for hours! Your help is very much appreciated.