# Get value of a row based on a column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I want to get value in other sheet based on a column for Example.

If the value of Z2 is 10 on sheet 1 than on sheet 2 I want to get value of A10 if value of Z2 is 25 than i need sheet 2 to get value of A25 and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic INDIRECT formula with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437086/dynamic-indirect-formula-with-range)

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
=indirect(address('sheet1'!z2, 1, 4, 1, "sheet1"))
```

Comment: thanks exactly what i was looking for :) can you please explain me a bit how formula work because i need to get multiple values Thanks a lot again